# How do I find the smallest number in a list of random integers on Python without using min()?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out why this code isn't working! The only part not working is the smallestNumber, it always comes back at zero? What am I doing wrong?

```
import random

X  = random.randint(10,15)

pickedNumber =int( input("Please enter a number: "))

print("Generating", (pickedNumber), "random Numbers between 20 and 50:")

for numberCount in range(1,pickedNumber+1):

    numberCount = random.randint(20,50)
    sum = 0
    sum += numberCount
    print(numberCount)

print('The sum = ',sum)
print('the average = ', sum/pickedNumber)

for pickedNumber in range(0,X,1):
    number  = random.randint(20,50)

    if pickedNumber== 0 or pickedNumber < smallestNumber:

       smallestNumber = pickedNumber

print('The smallest = ',smallestNumber)
```

Comment: Right off the bat, where are you generating your list? Also the indentation under the for loop is wrong, and you never define 'smallestNumber' before calling it in your if statement.  I assume you can't use min() because this is a homework problem?

Comment: Sorry! its actually not indented like that,on my end I viewed it differently when I was changing it into the code block let me see if I can fix it, first time actually writing a question on here my bad. I've also tried defining smallestNumber @ beginning of code but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @melissa please edit the answer. Copy-paste your full code; then select your code, and hit `ctrl-k` for `{}`.

Comment: Heres the code output currently: lease enter a number: 13
Generating 13 random Numbers between 20 and 50:
28
47
40
45
35
30
27
45
20
41
45
28
29
The sum =  29
the average =  2.230769230769231
The smallest =  0

Comment: @AnttiHaapala did it not get fixed? I thought I fixed all the indentation manually? Looks fine on my end

Comment: no, it is not correct. see the if statement in for loop. Anyhow, your problem is you assigned your loop index `pickedNumber` to the `smallestNumber` instead your random number `number`.

Comment: also I don't know the instructions but I guess you'd want to have the logic of the latter loop in the former for it getting the minimum random number of those from the *first* loop...

Comment: lordy lord okay I think I finally got it indented correctly,  okay so I totally would believe I have an assignment error bc I did some pretty poor naming on this assignment, but if I change pickednumber to my random number, number it still pulls zero for smallest number. Also thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code that I won't address directly, but as for finding the smallest item in a list of integers, simply sort the list and return the first item in the list:

```
some_list = [5,7,1,9]
sorted_list = sorted(some_list)
smallest = sorted_list[0]
>>> smallest
1
```

You don't necessarily need to create a second list to store the sorted result, it is simply there to illustrate the difference.

EDIT: You could also just store the first random int generated as `smallestNumber` and then as each new random int is created, compare it to `smallestNumber` and if the new int is smaller, set `smallestNumber` to it.

Example:

```
//stuff to generate random int done here
smallest = new_random_int

//generate the next random int
if next_random_int < smallest:
    smallest = next_random_int
```

And so on, where `new_random_int` is the very first random integer you generate, and `next_random_int` is any random int you generate after that.

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Though this would work, OP already had the idea of an asymptotically better algorithm in the question...

Comment: so basically its supposed to have the user enter their number and the code is supposed print out that many random numbers and then from that list of randomly generated numbers figure out the smallest, average, sum, and eventually I'll put in largest. How exactly can I put those random ints in a list?

Comment: @melissa you could define an empty list and use the `.append()` method to add in the random ints as they are created.  Storing these in a list would make it easy to find those other results.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree. I edited my answer to include what I think the OPs assignment might have been shooting for.

Comment: oh right right, I hear what your saying but yea I feel like he didn't specifically write that we couldn't use append but I feel it might be frowned upon since hes not letting us use a lot of functions.

Comment: How exactly do you go about setting the first random int as smallestNumber? I also am going to have to repeat a similar process for the largest number as well, and I still tbh am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @melissa `append` is about as basic as it gets. All it does is add an item to a List object.  It isn't doing much behind-the-scenes magic for you like `min()` does.  Think of `append` more like `+, -, *, /`, its kind of an essential thing when dealing with List objects.

Comment: @ eziegl you're right now that I think about it append shouldn't be an issue, so how would I write a list with the random ints for some reason I just can't wrap my head around it, something like list = random.randint(20,50)? that just doesn't look right lol

Comment: You would wrap your int creation in a for loop based on the number the user picked. First, create an empty list `some_list = []` and then in the for loop: `some_list.append(random.randint(x,y))`

Comment: @eziegl I'm sorry, I'm really trying to get this, I don't really get what append does I guess, what exactly am I appending as far as (x,y) I am at a loss for what should even go there, currently I have this: for number in range(0,X,1):
     smallestNumberlist.append(random.randint(0,X,1)) and I know that not right

Comment: I would recommend reading through the tutorials point article about lists, but specifically this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

Comment: @ eziegl I'm just not understanding how to append a random integer honestly. Like if it were 200 I see how you append that but if I'm trying to look at each random int and then see if one is bigger than the other and so on to see whats smallest I just don't understand how to go from the random ints that get listed by my numberCount to appending them to the end of a list? Do you have any examples of lists and random integers because I'm just not getting it...

Comment: You would store your random integer in a temporary variable and use the variable to append to the list, and compare to the smallest. `temp = randomint(etc);  mylist.append(temp);  if temp < smallest; smallest = temp`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I ended up figuring it out and doing it this way.

```
import random

largest = 0

sum = 0

pickedNumber =random.randint(10,15)

print("Generating", (pickedNumber), "random Numbers between 20 and 50:")

number = random.randint(20,50)
sum += number 
print(number)
largest = number
smallest = number 


for numberCount in range(1,pickedNumber):
    number = random.randint(20,50)
    print(number)
    sum += number
    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number 
    if number > largest:
        largest = number 



print('The sum = ',sum)
print('the average = ', "{:.2f}".format( sum/pickedNumber))
print('the largest = ', largest)
print('The smallest = ',smallest)
```